# Как правильно настроить file-io-dispatcher в akka?

Tags: scala, akka-http, akka

Попытался поднять сервер с `akka`. При загрузке настроек `ConfigFactory.load()` с `akk-http` возникает такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution: reference.conf @ jar:file:/home/faoxis/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http_2.12/jars/akka-http_2.12-10.1.5.jar!/reference.conf: 51: Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher}
```

Нашел в исходниках `akka-http` такую строку конфигурации:

```
# Fully qualified config path which holds the dispatcher configuration
  # to be used by FlowMaterialiser when creating Actors for IO operations.
  file-io-dispatcher = ${akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher}
```

Возник вопрос. Могу я воспользоваться каким-то функционалом по умолчанию и не прокидывать значение `akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher` через переменную окружения? Могу я как-то настроить это через `application.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется оно не может считать значение `blocking-io-dispatcher`

Возможно надо добавить эту конфигурацию в `application.conf`

```
akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher = "akka.stream.default-blocking-io-dispatcher"
```

[Документация](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/stream/stream-configuration.html)